# Google Sheets, remove leading apostrophe in cells automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a project that entails a Google Sheet receiving data from an iOS app. The app scans a barcode and pops timestamp and code into the sheet. If you look at the sheet, it appears to be fine.

```
A                        B
2020-09-07 08:42:50      1234 
2020-09-06 08:42:49      5678
2020-09-05 08:42:48      9101
```

If you click on any of the cells, each cell has a ' prepended to the front of the value.

```
A                         B
'2020-09-07 08:42:50      '1234 
'2020-09-06 08:42:49      '5678
'2020-09-05 08:42:48      '9101
```

The sheet will continually be populated as scans occur. I'm looking for a solution that removes that apostrophe (') from each cell automatically.

Thank you!

Comment: You want to remove the apostrophe using formulas or something incorporated into a script ? If you want the latter, what have you tried so far?

Comment: A better way is just to fix the input/ios app, which sends data as string

Comment: `function removeApos() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  const vs=rg.getDisplayValues();
  vs.map(function(r,i){
    if(r[0].slice(0,1)=="'")r[0].splice(0,1);
    if(r[1].slice(0,1)=="'")r[1].splice(0,1);
  });
  rg.setValues(vs);
}`

Comment: @Cooper I may be wrong but that apostrophe `'` is silent(only used to denote that it is text type). I don't think it'll show up in `getDisplayValues()` or `getValues()`. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Actually I used a single quote and I tested it.  It works.

Comment: @Cooper I see. I just tested and in my environment, I can't seem to reproduce.  The `'` is missing in both getDisplayValues and getValues

Comment: The question looks to be opinion-based. What kind of solution you are looking? Are you able to change how the iOS app sends the data to the spreadsheet? By the other hand, how is the data placed on the spreadsheet? Are they added one row at a time or they are added by batches? How frequently is the spreadsheet updated?

Comment: I notice that a single quote doesn't actually display in the cell but it does in the top row for the active cell.

Comment: @Rubén This question is NOT likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.  Infact there are no opinions only facts. Is research lacking? Yes. Is search efforts lacking? Yes. But I really don't think it's attracting or likely to attract a opinion based answer

Comment: @Cooper Yes. As I said, it is only used to denote a text type. It won't actually be displayed. OP also says this: "If you look at the sheet, it appears to be fine."

Comment: @TheMaster: Solution 1

Change the iOS app

Solution 2

Do a copy/paste

Solution 3

Use Google Sheets built-in functions

Solution 4

Use Google Apps Script . All of these solutions have several ways to be implemented and in either case what will be the criteria to say that one solution is better than other if the OP didn't included any hint for that?

Comment: @Rubén But none of those solutions are opinions. OP is not asking for a best way. There are [many ways to skin a cat](https://wiktionary.org/wiki/there%27s_more_than_one_way_to_skin_a_cat). I'm sure most, if not all questions here  can be provided with many solutions. Edit: OP might not even be looking for a  code by code implementation, but just a plain solution- like the one I provided -which method or even just why.

Comment: I am not the iOS app developer, but I did send them a note to see if they can adjust how data is sent to the sheet.

Comment: @DarrellSchulte Are you still interested for a simple solution using just a formula? If so, please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe `'` prefix simply requests that the data in that not be parsed to a different type.

A better way to fix the issue is just to fix the input/ios app, which specifically sends data as string/raw data. If the app uses sheets api, the [`valueInputOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) needs  to be set to `USER_ENTERED` and NOT `RAW`.

Alternatively, You can use [time triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to clear  using [`range.clear`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearoptions) with `formatOnly:true`. If that doesn't work, You should  explicitly [`setNumberFormat`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats) to the specific format needed: `0` for number  and `mm-dd-yyyy` for date and so on.

Answer (score 2):

#### How to remove leading apostrophe in cells using a formula

Since the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766738/google-sheets-remove-leading-apostrophe-in-cells-automatically#comment112760627_63766738):

> *You want to remove the apostrophe using formulas or something incorporated into a script?*

is not answered, I take it you would not mind a formula solution as well.

---

You can use either a query formula

```
=QUERY(A2:B)
```

or an arrayformula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:B)
```

```
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|        Original Data          | Using  =QUERY(A2:B)          |
|                               | Or     =ARRAYFORMULA(A2:B)   |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| `07/09/2020 08:42:50  | `1234 | 07/09/2020 08:42:50   | 1234 |
| `06/09/2020 08:42:49  | `5678 | 06/09/2020 08:42:49   | 5678 |
| `05/09/2020 08:42:48  | `9101 | 05/09/2020 08:42:48   | 9101 |
+-----------------------+-------+-----------------------+------+
```

---

**EDIT**
*(following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766738/google-sheets-remove-leading-apostrophe-in-cells-automatically/63856071#comment112919705_63856071))*

> *But the type of cell(=type()) isn't changed.*

I order to change the values from text to numbers one can use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:B<>"",A2:B*1,))
```

*Just make sure to format the Date time values accordingly.*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Testing this, even `=A2:B` seems to work. But the type of cell(`=type()`) isn't changed.

Comment: @TheMaster *"But the type of cell(`=type()`) isn't changed"*. Do you probably mean that it remains a text? *"Testing this, even `=A2:B` seems to work."* Actually it would not. It needs to be an array.

Comment: Apologies. You're right. I missed braces during my previous comment. It should be `={A2:B}`. *Do you probably mean that it remains a text?* Yes. I think that's the reason for the apostrophe `'` in the first place.